# Delete database entry on click of delete button. The data is showed through loop from database

Tags: php, sql, ajax

As of click on fb share button a new small window/div is appeared to ask options like share with friends or private, same as i want to show.
My data is showing through loop from database and i want if a loop element is clicked a new div is appeared to confirm to delete that entry and on click of confirm button that entry should be deleted from database other while escape

Comment: Please add your code here so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an idea:

```
    start loop here

    <input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deletefunction(id_from_loop);'>

    end loop here



    <script>

    function deletefunction(id_to_delete)
    {
var x = confirm("Delete record ?");
            if (x == true) {
                //do the deleting routine (ajax, etc) here, then refresh the page.
            } else {
                return false;
            }

    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your page add code like this.

Catch PHP action

```
<?php

if($_GET['delete_id']){
  //sql query to delete your record

}
?>
```

HTML delete link

```
<a href="http://example.com?delete_id=<?php echo $data['id'];?>" onclick="return doconfirm('<?php echo $data['id'];?>'">  </a>
```

Javascript confirm pop:

```
<script>
function doconfirm(Id){

    var res = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this element?");
    if(res === true){
      // will go to link
      retrun true;

    }else{
        alert("You just same me man! Thank you.");
    }
}
</script>
```